# JSON text format

Tags: java

```
[
  {
    "firstName":"Ivan",
    "lastName":"Petrov",
    "birthDate":"1993-03-09",
    "email":"kazakhsam",
    "address":{
        "country":"Russia",
        "city":"Moscow",
        "street":"Lenin",.
        "buildingNo":"10"
     }
  }
]
```

It gives me this error:

> org.json.JSONException: A JSONObject text must begin with '{' at 1 [character 2 line 1]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yeah, remove dot as @KishanCS said.

Comment: https://jsonlint.com/ is your friend, you don't need to ask here

Comment: @KishanCS sorry, I always flip comma and dot :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `JSON` is not valid. You have an extra dot character after `"Lenin",.`

Cou can validate you JSON String with online validators, I suggest you to use this one: https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/

If you paste your JSON there then it tells excatly what is wrong with your json string:

- Error:Strings should be wrapped in double quotes.[Code 17, Structure
  34]
- Error:Invalid characters found.[Code 18, Structure 34]

Use jsonlint.com to check for correct indentation.

Answer (score 0):

This is a json array not json object try to parse array object.